# oTree: How to access the player's id from the player class in model.py?

Tags: python, django, otree

I would like to define a parameter variable via the default attribute id_in_group of the player. However, this attribute does not seem to be accessible via the ways I could think of (such as via BasePlayer.id_in_group).

The code of the class player:

```
class Player(BasePlayer):
    investment_amount = models.CurrencyField(
        doc="""
        Amount invested by this player.
        """,
        min=0, max=Constants.endowment
    )
    random_number = BasePlayer.id_in_group

    def set_payoffs(self):
        for p in self.get_players():
            p.payoff = 110
```

How could I access the attribute id_in_group? Or is it impossible due to the fact that it is a default attribute preset by oTree?

Comment: Why do you want to define `random_number` at all?

Comment: Different pictures are shown to different subjects corresponding to this random_number.

Comment: But why wouldn't you just use `id_in_group`? Why assign it to a different name?

Comment: I thought I could assess the attribute via another object, which would be a long name if I did not assign it another name. In case you are wondering, directly using id_in_group also does not work.

Comment: But `random_number` is *longer* than `id_in_group`! I can't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

in oTree the `id_in_group` attribute is assigned after the session started. It is quite logical because the groups haven't been formed yet before the session started.

You are trying to assign a value in the Player class declaration, when none of players have been assigned to groups, thus no one has his/her `id_in_group`.

Moreover, you assign a value to a property of the model, not to the fields of specific instances (i.e. players). If you need to assign to `random_id` field of each Player a specific value based on his/her id in group do the following:

in **models.py**:

```
class Player(BasePlayer):
     random_id = models.IntegerField()

class Subsession(BaseSubsession):
     def before_session_starts(self):
         for p in self.get_players():
             p.random_id = p.id_in_group
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried accessing the variable via `super.id_in_group` or `self.id_in_group`?  If it's a variable of the parent class, you wouldn't call the class directly like you are doing.

Also, Google has a ton of results for how to access parent class variables, a lot of which are answers from stackoverflow that explain things really well :-)

Comment: When I used "super", the error was: type object 'super' has no attribute 'id_in_group'; when I used 'self', the error was: Unresolved reference 'self'. I don't think it has anything to do with parent class. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: Can you post the BasePlayer class code?  It seems odd that `self` wouldn't solve problem assuming you have your inheritance set correctly.

Comment: `super` is a function, and wouldn't make sense at that point anyway; `self` is only available inside a method.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt BasePlayer is prewritten by otree developers. I don't know where it is.